# pretty-faces raison of StackOverflowError during deployment

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, prettyfaces

I use `pretty-faces` during the deployment, i have error

```
 Exception starting filter Pretty Filter
    java.lang.StackOverflowError
        at java.util.LinkedList.isPositionIndex(LinkedList.java:539)
        at java.util.LinkedList.checkPositionIndex(LinkedList.java:557)
        at java.util.LinkedList.listIterator(LinkedList.java:865)
        at java.util.AbstractList.listIterator(AbstractList.java:299)
        at java.util.AbstractSequentialList.iterator(AbstractSequentialList.java:239)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1064)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1063)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection$1.<init>(Collections.java:1064)
        at java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableCollection.iterator(Collections.java:1063)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.PrettyConfig.getMappingById(PrettyConfig.java:174)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:58)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
        at com.ocpsoft.pretty.faces.config.spi.ParentingPostProcessor.createAncestry(ParentingPostProcessor.java:66)
```

Comment: Which are your prettyfaces mappings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As this happens in ParentingPostProcessor, I guess you have a cycle in your mapping hierarchy. Perhaps something like this:

```
<url-mapping id="my-id" parentId="my-id"> 
    ...
</url-mapping>
```

Make sure that there are no cycles in the hierarchy which will probably fix this issue.

See this section of the documentation for details:

http://ocpsoft.org/docs/prettyfaces/3.3.3/en-US/html/Configuration.html#config.mapping.parents